# Making a Highscore with the option to challenge players. But you cannot see your own account

Tags: php, html

as i am a total newbie @ php/html i thought i'd ask here how to fix my problem.
Quick info: At the moment i am building a webpage fighting game. The highscore shows everybody but yourself with an href that links to a site that challenges them to fight against you. I have a MySQL data base filled with infos(like a playerID,Wins,Losses so on). So i have two questions: 1. How would i implement my own/your account to be visible, but not being clickable(because you shouldnt be able to challenge yourself) and how would i make them sort by the highest number of the Win/Loss Ratio(this one is not implemented into the database)?
Here is my code :

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "mydatabase","----");
    mysql_select_db("mydata");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `player` WHERE player_ID != ".$playerID." ORDER BY Wins DESC";
    if(!$result = mysql_query($query)){
        echo mysql_error();
    }

            echo "<div id='highscore'>";
            echo "<table class='text' id='highscore' >";
            echo            "<tr class= $fontarray[$i]>";
            echo                "<th></th>";
            echo                "<th>PLAYER</th>";
            echo                "<th>WINS</th>";
            echo                "<th>LOSSES</th>";
            echo                "<th>W/L</th>";
            echo            "</tr>";
            echo    "<br class='clear'/ >";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

                echo "<tr class= $fontarray[$i]>";
                echo "<td>";    
                echo $placearray[$i];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<a class='nodecoration' href=\"pickmove.php?id=".$row['player_ID']."\"/>  ".$row['nickname']." <a/>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $row['Wins'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $row['Losses'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo round($row['Wins']/$row['Losses'], 2);
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $i = $i+1;

            }?>
            </table>
            </div>
```

if you need more information, ill try to pass it on to you. 
Thanks for reading!

Edit: Cheers for the answers, but they're a bit too complicated for me (i am either too new or too stupid). If you could make them as simple as possible i'd be greatful.

Comment: __1.__ Remove `player_ID != ".$playerID."` then in your HTML, check `if ($row['player_ID'] == $playerID)` then remove the anchor to challenge and just output the name as a string. __2.__ Loop through the array and calculate the W/L ratio then use [`usort()`](http://uk1.php.net/usort) to sort them before outputting the HTML.

Comment: It's better to make comment to the answers than to append it to your question. Just a tip!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if `$row['player_ID']` matches `$playerID`, if it does, do not print a link. And remove the playerID check from sql query.
2. `SELECT ..., (Wins/Losses) AS ratio` and then `ORDER BY ratio DESC`.

Here is your code modified:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "mydatabase","----");
mysql_select_db("mydata");

$query = "SELECT player_ID, Wins, Losses, (Wins/Losses) AS ratio FROM `player` ORDER BY Wins DESC";
if(!$result = mysql_query($query)){
    echo mysql_error();
}

        echo "<div id='highscore'>";
        echo "<table class='text' id='highscore' >";
        echo            "<tr class= $fontarray[$i]>";
        echo                "<th></th>";
        echo                "<th>PLAYER</th>";
        echo                "<th>WINS</th>";
        echo                "<th>LOSSES</th>";
        echo                "<th>W/L</th>";
        echo            "</tr>";
        echo    "<br class='clear'/ >";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

            echo "<tr class= $fontarray[$i]>";
            echo "<td>";    
            echo $placearray[$i];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo ($row['player_ID'] != $player_ID ? "<a class='nodecoration' href=\"pickmove.php?id=".$row['player_ID']."\"/>  ".$row['nickname']." <a/>" : $row['nickname'] );
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['Wins'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['Losses'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo round($row['Wins']/$row['Losses'], 2);
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $i = $i+1;

        }?>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: First of all cheers, but with this query i dont get any of my playerIDs nor nicknames, therefore the table doesnt get filled with the nicknames. i realised it after trying for a longer time.
PS: the query to get all the data wouldve been "SELECT `player_ID`, `nickname`, `Wins`, `Losses` FROM `pruegelpause_player` ORDER BY Wins DESC", but now it works totally fine

Comment: The nickname column must've slipped out of my vision. Glad to hear you worked it out anyhow.